# Docker-Compose Wordpress: wp_mail() not working

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, mail-server

I run a WordPress installation in a docker-container with the WordPress image (https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/). My problem is that I can't send mails via `wp_mail()` or with PHP `mail()`.

When I try to call a `mail()`-function I get an "Internal Server Error".

What can I do? Do I need a external mail server?

**My docker-compose.yml:**

```
wordpress:
image: wordpress
container_name: shk_wordpress
links:
 - mariadb:mysql
environment:
 - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=admin
ports:
 - "8000:80"
volumes:
 - ./app:/var/www/html
 - ./theme/:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/shk-theme
mariadb:
image: mariadb
container_name: shk_mariadb
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
volumes:
 - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
phpmyadmin:
image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
container_name: shk_phpmyadmin
environment:
  - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
  - MYSQL_USER=root
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
ports:
  - "9000:80"
links:
  - "mariadb:mysql"
```

Comment: Do you have any error logging? This could possibly be because your docker image doesn't have the correct port open likely 25

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this problem was already been discused at WP docker image repo.
Checkout this answer on
[Github](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/30#issuecomment-94952430)

Further down you might find some other solutions to your problem if that one doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :

In your docker-compose.yml, replace

```
image: wordpress
```

by

```
build: .
```

Step 2 :

Create a Dockerfile :

```
FROM wordpress
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ssmtp
RUN echo "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/sendmail.ini
RUN sed -i -e 's/mailhub=mail/mailhub=[IP RELAY SERVER]/' /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
RUN sed -i -e 's/#rewriteDomain=/rewriteDomain=[IP RELAY SERVER]/' /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
RUN sed -i -e '/hostname=/d' /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

Step 3 :
Replace [IP RELAY SERVER]